Where to Find GitLab API v4 Swagger/OpenAPI Specification?
I'm looking for the Swagger/OpenAPI specification file for GitLab API version 4 mainly for /api/v4/personal_access_tokens. I've searched extensively but couldn't find it.
Can someone please point me in the right direction or provide any insights on where I can locate this file? Thank you!

here's the OpenAPI v4 description available in their git repo.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/api/openapi/openapi.yaml?plain=1

I would appreciate your quick response, but I'm mainly looking for personal access tokens, which are not available in the specified link above

doesn't look like they have them documented

Thank you for the path of the YAML file. There is a v2 version YAML file which contains all the token paths.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/api/openapi/openapi_v2.yaml?ref_type=heads

This (PATs) is a new feature added in recent releases of GitLab. However, the OpenAPI specs updating merge request was approved 3 days ago. The history of the merge request can be found at the following link: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/147122
